# Removing an item from the dictionary "grocery_list" causes an error

Tags: python, dictionary

I seem to receive an error every time I try to remove an item from the dictionary. Here's my code:

```
print("  MY NEW AND IMPROVED GROCERY LIST  ")


def grocerylist():
    hist_grocery = []

    grocery = True

    while grocery:
        choice = str(input("\n=====================\nWhat would you like to do? \n1 - Add an item\n2 - Remove an item "
                           "\n3 - Print entire list\n4 - Calculate cost\n5 - Exit program\nChoice: "))

        if choice == "1":
            print("=====================\nADD AN ITEM\n")

            information = input("Give the following information:   \nItem name: ")
            price = input("Item price: ")
            quantity = input("Item quantity: ")

            grocery_list = {"Item name": str(information), "price": float(price), "quantity": int(quantity)}

            hist_grocery.append(grocery_list)

     **   elif choice == "2":
            print("=====================\nREMOVE AN ITEM\n")
            remove_item = str(input("What would you like to remove? \nItem name: ")).format()  # format function

            grocery_list = [i for i in hist_grocery if str(i).lower() != remove_item]
**

        elif choice == "3":
            print("=====================\nPRINTING LIST...")
            if hist_grocery == []:
                print("The grocery list is empty!")
            else:
                [print(items, end="\t   ") for items in grocery_list.values()]
```

Here's what I inputted: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nbfn.png)

Tried removing the item egg but it became an error.

Here's what the terminal says:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZ0rD.png)

I tried creating another for loop but somehow I got confused along the process. What should I change in my code?

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

Your error isn't with deleting an item it's with printing the items.

Since you didn't choose option 1 first there is no existing object grocery_list. I'm speculating a bit here but I assume the interpreter sees the for-each loop and assumes that it must be a list, which doesn't have a `.values()` method so it gives you this error.

I would try declaring an empty dictionary before your first if block.

Comment: oh my bad I forgot to include the picture where I added values to the program.

Answer (score 0):

The error has almost nothing to do with the "delete" option. The error is in the "print" option. If you look in the code for choice 2, you see that `grocery_list = [i...]`, which is definitely a `list`. As the error clearly states, you cannot use `.values()` with a `list`, like when you tried to do so in the 3rd option, where `[...for items in grocery_list.values()]`.

PS: Please don't post your error as a picture. It makes it easier for all those involved if it's typed out in the actual question.